# Выделенный IP адрес

Tags: ip, хостинг

Возможно ли на российских хостингах подключить выделенный зарубежный IP?

Answer (score 1):

Теоретически такое возможно, если хостинг провайдер является реселлером другого зарубежного или размещает сервера в зарубежном датацентре (*что крайне маловероятно*). Но, в любом случае данную информацию необходимо уточнять у конкретного хостинг провайдера.

***P.S.***
С реселлерами связываться, по возможности, не советую. Качество услуг зачастую хуже, чем у "обычного" хостинга.